# Check If Domain Exists In Specific Schema

Tags: postgresql

When running:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'my_domain_identifier';
```

I can see my domain info there so I can check it exists. How can I tell if it exists in a specific schema?

There is `typnamespace` in the results but I'm unsure of how to link that to a specific schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it, you just need to add in the typnamespace, as you suspected:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'my_domain_identifier'
AND typnamespace = 'your_schema'::regnamespace;
```